# Not having latest revision after using pod

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use this project :

https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView

This is my podfile.

```
target "Name" do

#pod 'CBZSplashView', '> 0.1.1'

end
```

This is what I see :

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing CBZSplashView (1.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

But inside the files under the Pods folder, I do not see the latest code, although it is supposed to bring latest revision (1.0.0)

For example, [in Github under classes](https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView/blob/master/Classes/CBZSplashView.m) I see different code than the one in xcode.

In particular in xcode I do not see these two classes, which were added after 0.1.1

```
+ (instancetype)splashViewWithIcon:(UIImage *)icon backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
  /* This component is useless without an icon */
  NSParameterAssert(icon);

  return [[CBZRasterSplashView alloc] initWithIconImage:icon backgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}

+ (instancetype)splashViewWithBezierPath:(UIBezierPath *)bezier backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
{
  return [[CBZVectorSplashView alloc] initWithBezierPath:bezier backgroundColor:backgroundColor];
}
```

Is it something am I doing wrong or the Github project has some problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the author hasn't created a new tag in the repo since they released the 1.0.0 version. If you'd like to use the newest commit from the repo you can specify the `:head` option as described [here](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod).

In your Podfile you would use:

```
pod "foo", ":head"
```

Then when you run `pod install` the repo will be cloned and it will use the newest commit. Note that this can be dangerous depending on how authors handle the stability of master. Also when you run `pod update` it will automatically move to the newest commit at that point, which could break your project at anytime, as this does not follow semantic versioning (although `>` doesn't either).

You could also submit an [issue](https://github.com/callumboddy/CBZSplashView/issues) asking the library author to add a new tag and push a new version of their podspec.